# iPhone 4 background location service question

Tags: iphone, sdk, location

I'm looking into the new background location service options in the iPhone 4 SDK. It allows an app to run in the background and receive location updates from the device.

There are two methods offered. One is a battery intensive mode that continuously gets location updates. The second recommended method sends the app location updates when there has been a "significant location change".

Does anyone know what a significant location change might be? Is a 30 foot walk considered significant, or is a 10 block walk considered significant? I imagine it also depends on the accuracy of the location mechanism being used at the time.

Comment: OS 4 is under NDA, so you'd be better off asking in the official Apple forums.

Comment: link for the lazy https://devforums.apple.com/community/iphone/40beta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've recently done some field testing of the new background location service to get an idea of what constitutes a significant location update, what kind of accuracy to expect for the location hits and our general experiences using it.

The results are detailed in a fairly lengthy blog post:

[iPhone Background GPS: Accurate to 500 meters, not enough for foot traffic](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/07/22/iphone-background-gps-accurate-to-500-meters-not-enough-for-foot-traffic/#more-480)

Answer (score 3):

As Steve Jobs mentioned in the OS 4 introduction, the low power mode uses cell tower triangulation and does not activate GPS unit. Since the iPhone phone module needs to keep a connection to the cell network anyway, there should be no impact on battery life.

Since the precision of a location fix with cell tower triangulation is anywhere between a few dozen meters (in dense city locations) and a few miles, I think 30 ft is not a significant location change. I don't know the specifics, though (and as mentioned by the commenters, the Apple dev forums are the right place to talk about those).

Comment: Thanks for the details. By "low power mode", you're referring to the non-continious update method, correct? Presumably the constantly updating method would need to be GPS driven if it was going to be used for driving directions and whatnot.

Also, I was not aware of the NDA. Will look further on the Apple forums.

Thanks all.

Comment: Yes, by "low power mode" I mean the non-continuous update method. The other method uses the GPS unit.

Comment: I do not understand why people continue to talk about questions when we are still (and were then) covered by the NDA!  Ask in the correct place:  The Apple Dev Forums.