# How to notify when location change in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I am using CLLocationManager class find the current location.When app in background, I want to notify the user while location change using LocalPushnotification, How to set it?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789994/iphone-4-background-location-service-question) to get the current location when user is in background.

After you get the location send it to your server.

Process the data on the server and create you push notification and send it to apple server.

Good luck